# Android: How to pass uri from onActivity result to another method?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, uri

How do i pass an uri from the onActivity result to another method in the same jave file.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
        Uri mVideoURI = data.getData();
        videoView.setVideoURI(mVideoURI);
        videoView.start();
    }

}
```

method savevideo:

```
public void savevideo() {


String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/SavedVideo/";
    File dir = new File(path);
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();;
    // create unique identifier
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 100;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    // create file name
    String videoName = "Video_" + n + ".mp4";
    File fileVideo = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), videoName);

    try {
        fileVideo.createNewFile();
        success = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (success) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video saved!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Error during video saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return true;

}

}
```

I would like like pass the mVideoURI to savevideo method and then save the video uri into gallery. Can someone help me with this. Any guidance/suggestion would be really helpful. Thank you.

EDITED: FULL CODING:

```
public class AndroidVideoPlayer extends Activity {

Button button;
VideoView videoView;
private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_video_player);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setType("video/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
        Uri mVideoURI = data.getData();
        savevideo(mVideoURI);
        videoView.setVideoURI(mVideoURI);
        videoView.start();
    }

}
public void savevideo(Uri mVideoURI) {


    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/SavedVideo/";
    File dir = new File(path);
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();;
    // create unique identifier
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 100;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    // create file name
    String videoName = "Video_" + n + ".mp4";
    File fileVideo = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), videoName);

    boolean success=false;
    try {
        fileVideo.createNewFile();
        success = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (success) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video saved!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Error during video saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



}

}
```

Comment: you can call saveVideo method from onActivityResult and pass the Uri

Comment: saveVideo(mVideoURI)   public void savevideo(Uri mVideoURI) ??

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding from your question, you have to call a method after getting a result from another activity. so you might be called `startActivitForResult(activityB)` for getting the video Uri. so you will get a callback from the `activityB`, thus you can directly pass the video to the method `saveVideo()` since it is in the same Activity.

**Example**

```
   @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) 
      return;

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
        Uri mVideoURI = data.getData();
        saveVideo(videoUri);
    }
}

public void saveVideo(Uri videoUri){
  // do operations with uri
}
```

or if you can't accept any arguments in `saveVideo()` method you can make `uri` as a member variable and use `inside()` method

Comment: when i execute using this method the video is saved in gallery but i cant play the video as it is 0kb..is there something wrong with my coding?

Answer (score 1):

use this code-

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
        Uri mVideoURI = data.getData();
        saveVideo(mVideoURI);                // methode to save uri gets called here
        videoView.setVideoURI(mVideoURI);
        videoView.start();
    }

}
method savevideo:

public void savevideo(Uri mVideoURI) {


String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/SavedVideo/";
    File dir = new File(path);
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();;
    // create unique identifier
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 100;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    // create file name
    String videoName = "Video_" + n + ".mp4";
    File fileVideo = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), videoName);

    try {
        fileVideo.createNewFile();
        success = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (success) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video saved!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Error during video saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return true;

}

}
```

Comment: the video is saved in gallery but i cant play the video..the video file is 0kb..do you know why its like this? @sud

Comment: this is because may be your file does not getting saved in gallery successfully or to play video you are giving wrong path of video file to player

Comment: i have added my full coding..can u guide me where did i make mistake?im feeling a bit lost. @sud

Comment: the 'mVideoURI' in [ public void savevideo(Uri mVideoURI) ] is highlighted in grey and says the parameter is never used.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are only creating new file on your destination path but not write the data of source file to destination file.

So you are getting 0KB file. Use the below code code for writing a file.

```
void savefile(URI sourceuri)
{
String sourceFilename= sourceuri.getPath();
String destinationFilename = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+File.separatorChar+"abc.mp3";

BufferedInputStream bis = null;
BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

try {
  bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFilename));
  bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destinationFilename, false));
  byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
  bis.read(buf);
  do {
    bos.write(buf);
  } while(bis.read(buf) != -1);
} catch (IOException e) {

} finally {
  try {
    if (bis != null) bis.close();
    if (bos != null) bos.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {

  }
}
}
```

Comment: i have added my coding in ur answer..the video is not saved into designated folder? is there anything wrong with the coding? @Mayur Sakhiya

Comment: yes, my above answer said that in your code , you forgot to write a video data to your saved file. pls check my answer properly and implement above code to save your video file

Comment: i followed your answer exactly expect that i customised the location of the video to be saved..but its not working..@Mayur Sakhiya